# "Internalize someone else's pain into my own pain"?

Tags: expressions

Is "you must internalize someone else's pain into your own pain" grammatically correct?

It basically means you not only need to understand other people's pain, but you should also feel and treat the pain as if it was your own.

I *have* to use the work "internalize", and want to know if the rest of the sentence after "internalize" is grammatically correct and whether "pain" after "own" can also be omitted.

And, dose it mean the same as "you should think of someone else's pain as your own?"

Comment: Why do you 'HAVE' to use it? Any specific reason?

Comment: It's unnecessarily wordy. **You must internalise someone else's pain** says it all. **Into your own pain** adds nothing to the meanng.